# Pass thrust device_vectors to device function and modify them

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

when I'm running this piece of code, the compiler says I'm calling a host function from global function.
I want to assing something a bit more complicated than zeros to A[i] and B[i] but I just wanted to test the functionality.
I need to modify values in both vectors.
Later I'd like to reduce the table A.

```
int main(void){
    const int numElements = 100000;
    thrust::device_vector<double> A(numElements);
    thrust::device_vector<double> B(numElements);
    int threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
    vectorCount<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(A, B, numElements);
}

__global__ void vectorCount(thrust::device_vector<double> A, thrust::device_vector<double> B, int numElements, int sequence_k){
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    A[i] = 0;
    B[i] = 0;
}
```

I've tried to change it to

```
struct saxpy_functor
{
    const int numElements;

    saxpy_functor(int _a) : numElements(_a) {}

    __host__ __device__
        double operator()(double& x) const {
        x = 0;
        return 0;
    }
};

//in main
thrust::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), saxpy_functor(numElements));
```

But I can't find how to get *i* as in previous example, since i want to perform calculations dependant on the *possition* in the Vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spite of its naming, a `thrust::device_vector` is not directly usable in CUDA device code. The `device_vector` is an object/container, and it is intended to be usable in host code only.  This is why you get the messages about "calling a host function..."

For the example you have shown here, to access the data directly, you would (in host code) extract device pointers to the underlying data in each container (`A` and `B`) and pass those pointers to your CUDA kernel.

Something like this:

```
int main(void){
    const int numElements = 100000;
    thrust::device_vector<double> A(numElements);
    thrust::device_vector<double> B(numElements);
    double *d_A = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(A.data());
    double *d_B = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(B.data());
    int threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
    vectorCount<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, numElements);
}

__global__ void vectorCount(double *A, double *B, int numElements){
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < numElements){
      A[i] = 0;
      B[i] = 0;}
}
```

Ordinary usage of the `thrust::transform`/functor method won't allow random access to the underlying data.  However you can use an "un-thrust-like" method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55999456/multiple-occurrence-subvector-search-with-cuda-thrust/56007654#56007654) to use the functor method and allow random access, if you wish.